# Chart.js where to add paddingRight property

Tags: chart.js

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas-chart").getContext("2d"),
                data = {
                    labels: [ "RP.800,000", "RP.400,000", "RP.200,000"],
                    datasets: [{
                            label: "",
                            data: [ "800000", "400000", "200000"],
                            borderColor: "#744c7e",
                            lineTension: 0,
                            pointBorderColor: "#bfc766",
                            pointBackgroundColor: "#bfc766"
                        }]
                };

        Chart.pluginService.register({
            beforeRender: function (chart) {
                if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
                    // create an array of tooltips
                    // we can't use the chart tooltip because there is only one tooltip per chart
                    chart.pluginTooltips = [];
                    chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                        chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function (sector, j) {
                            chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
                                _chart: chart.chart,
                                _chartInstance: chart,
                                _data: chart.data,
                                _options: chart.options,
                                _active: [sector]
                            }, chart));
                        });
                    });

                    // turn off normal tooltips
                    chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
                }
            },
            afterDraw: function (chart, easing) {
                if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
                    // we don't want the permanent tooltips to animate, so don't do anything till the animation runs atleast once
                    if (!chart.allTooltipsOnce) {
                        if (easing !== 1)
                            return;
                        chart.allTooltipsOnce = true;
                    }

                    // turn on tooltips
                    chart.options.tooltips.enabled = true;
                    Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function (tooltip) {
                        tooltip.initialize();
                        tooltip.update();
                        // we don't actually need this since we are not animating tooltips
                        tooltip.pivot();
                        tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
                    });
                    chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
                }
            }
        });


        var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: data,
            options: {
                legend:
                        {
                            display: false
                        },
                elements:
                        {
                            line:
                                    {
                                        fill: false
                                    }
                        },
                showAllTooltips: true,
                scales:
                        {
                            gridLines: {
                                offsetGridLines: true
                            },
                            xAxes: [{

                                    display: false

                                }],
                            yAxes: [{
                                    display: true,
                                    ticks: {
                                        min: 100000,
                                        max: 900000,
                                        fixedStepSize: 100000,
                                        callback: function (value) {
                                            return '';
                                        }
                                    }
                                }]
                        },
                tooltips: {
                    backgroundColor: '#92b95e',
                    titleColor: '#FFF',
                    titleFontStyle: 'normal',
                    xAlign: 'bottom',
                    callbacks: {
                        label: function () {
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k4pty0ds/

As you can see, the last tooltip got cut off.

According to the [Chart.js doc](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-writing-new-scale-types), I would like to add **paddingRight** and I do not know how. Please help.

I tried adding to scales and it doesn't work.

When i followed the documentation and used registerScaleType also failed.